# Questions about implementation of DBContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

I'm new in Asp.net world with its objects , So i have some questions:-

1- When do we create more than implementer class of DBContext not only one ?
2- In common pattern , I see which class derived from DBcontext that has property DBSet for every Entity
So why we do that ?
For me i create only generic repository also one class implementer of DBContext  that hasn't any property DBSet. is it rigth pattern ?

Thanks for your reply

Comment: Click here for more details [link](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/dbcontext.aspx)

Comment: @jishansiddique your edit claims "code formatted", but there was no code in the question. Do not use `inline code` to highlight random terms; this doesn't increase readability, but decreases it instead.

Comment: @CodeCaster ok thanks for updating me next time I'll look into :)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can, if you have multiple databases you can have a context for each.
2. DBSet represents a table in your database

Comment: No and no - each context represents a use case/Unit-of-Work, not a database. You can (*should*) have multiple contexts per database. A DbSet represents an entity in the *application* that maps to *something* in the database. That can be one or *more* tables in case of inheritance, views or even raw queries. It can have far fewer columns than the table itself, depending on the actual use case

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, sure , you are correct, however I tried to explain it to someone who is a newbie and tried to present ts as something that would be easy to understand. The point is you can multiple contexts with a multitude of implementations, i made a simple example of a use case

Answer (score 0):

About point 2 Always i don't populate any DBSet property for any table in DBContext implementer at all , only I populate it in the implementer of generic repository(Explained in the below) . So i Ask this question again , Is it considered a right practice ?

```
private DbSet<T> dbSet;
private StoreEntities storEntites;

protected IDBFactory dbFactory { get; set; }
protected StoreEntities DbContext
{
    get { return storEntites ?? (storEntites = dbFactory.init()); }
}

protected GenericReprositry(IDBFactory dbfactrty)
{
    dbFactory = dbfactrty;
    dbSet = DbContext.Set<T>();

}
```